# Visual Studio, OpenCV, Python - no webcam in app

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

Im trying to work with Visual Studio (and Visual Studio Code) in Python with OpenCV library.

I want to launch this code from OpenCV's samples that shows live video from my webcam:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But i get an exception in `cv2.imshow('frame',frame)` line that say:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

I installed OpenCV by `pip install opencv-python` from my command prompt

I get the same error when i work on Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio Code.

I checked privacy of my webcam, its visible to all my apps.

With Jupyter Notebook i can run this code perfectly.

Do you know the point, why i cant acces to my webcam from VS, but in Jupyter Notebook i can do it without any problems?

## EDIT 1

When i set

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` index into `-1` code compile, but i get black output. As i said before, in Jupyter i can get acces into my webcam in my laptop. Im using Windows 10

## EDIT2

When i add that line before `imshow()`:

```
    if ret:
        print("error")
        continue
```

I always get an `error` output in my command prompt. Even if i wait for a while, it stills printing "error". Like i said couple of times, in Jupyter Notebook i can launch my webcam by code above

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd want to unindent the block

```
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For now, it's nested in while(True) loop, thus releasing the capture prematurely and leading to reading error. 
Remember, in Python indents really matter.

Comment: I see. Then, try the following: insert 'if ret:' condition before imshow() function. Some webcams initialize slowly, and first frames from them can be read incorrectly.

Comment: I added `if ret:` line with print and it seems, like i get "error" all the time, i try to catch frame from webcam. Wait for a while but it always get an "ret" or "error" output. Look into my edit

Comment: Could you, by any chance, have installed several instances of OpenCV? I remember the similar problem I've stumbled upon when I installed OpenCV from source and left PyPI version intact.

Comment: Wait, I missed out on one thing. ret variable returns True if frame have been retrieved successfully, so you need to make your condition 'if not ret:', not the other way around.